# Как использовать скрипты из другого проекта google spreadsheet

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Написал скрипт в google spreadsheet для одной книги. Скрипт преобразует таблицу в json формат и делает еще пару, удобных для проекта, фич.

Теперь нужно подключить этот скрипт к остальным имеющимся книгам, коих около 20.

Как мне импортировать/подключить, а главное вызвать скрипт из одной книги в другой?
Доступ полный, владелец всего я.

Answer (score 0):

Наиболее прямой путь к многократному использованию кода - [библиотеки](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries) и [расширения (add-ons)](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview).

Те и другие имеют свои плюсы и минусы. Рекомендую начать с создания своих библиотек, так как этот путь проще для разработки и внедрения. Все подробности описаны в документации, пересказывать не стоит. Однако и в случае библиотек остаются действия вручную по их подключению и написанию или копированию минимального кода с обращением к их методам в каждой рабочей книге. Выигрыш в том, что оставшийся код - легко читаемый и управляемый. Внесение изменений и дополнений в библиотеку возможно и после
того, как Вы начали её многократно использовать, что также по-своему удобно.